# Center uneven portioned columns in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, web

My task is two center the two columns in one row, but i need their sizes to be col-md-6 here is my code

```
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3 post">
                 <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/500" alt="" /></a>
                <h2>DR. SAMUEL P. DIZON</h2><p align="justify">DR. SAMUEL P. DIZON,(SAMPLE CAPTION) M.D. is a Plan II Honors graduate from The University of Texas at Austin, and attended medical school at Baylor College of Medicine in Houston. She completed an internal medicine internship at University of Washington in Seattle and her anesthesiology residency at Baylor College of Medicine</p>

              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3 post">
                 <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/500" alt="" /></a>
                <h2>DR. Lady RUVI S. TAGULAO</h2><p>(Sample Text)Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam totam dolore facere nulla similique magni nobis beatae eveniet deserunt quisquam nihil autem. Maxime iste voluptate laboriosam veritatis possimus qui molestias numquam officia deleniti a! Debitis itaque tempora vel quas quidem natus fugit alias aliquam maiores deserunt quibusdam error laboriosam aut.
              </div>

            </div>
```

I know that making it 6-6 will make it go to center, but i dont want a big size for my elements

Comment: can you do a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solutions guys you just have to 2 divs before and after the divs you want to center, and you have to size them up to proportion the screen so it will be like this:

```
        <div class="row">


                //put an empty div here sized 2 <div class="col-md-2 post"></div>


              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3 post">
                 <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/500" alt="" /></a>
                <h2>DR. SAMUEL P. DIZON</h2><p align="justify">DR. SAMUEL P. DIZON,(SAMPLE CAPTION) M.D. is a Plan II Honors graduate from The University of Texas at Austin, and attended medical school at Baylor College of Medicine in Houston. She completed an internal medicine internship at University of Washington in Seattle and her anesthesiology residency at Baylor College of Medicine</p>

              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3 post">
                 <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/500" alt="" /></a>
                <h2>DR. Lady RUVI S. TAGULAO</h2><p>(Sample Text)Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam totam dolore facere nulla similique magni nobis beatae eveniet deserunt quisquam nihil autem. Maxime iste voluptate laboriosam veritatis possimus qui molestias numquam officia deleniti a! Debitis itaque tempora vel quas quidem natus fugit alias aliquam maiores deserunt quibusdam error laboriosam aut.
              </div>

              //and another 1 here <div class="col-md-2 post"></div>

            </div>
```